# No me funcionan las media queries en este reloj - Android

Tags: html, android, css

```js
var clock = document.querySelector('#utility-clock')
utilityClock(clock)
autoResize(clock, 295 + 32)

choose(clock, [
  ['hour', ['text', 'text-quarters', 'pill']],
  ['hour-text', ['large', 'small']],
  ['hour-display', ['all', 'quarters', 'none']],
  ['minute', ['line', 'dot']],
  ['minute-display', ['fine', 'fine-2', 'coarse', 'major', 'none']],
  ['minute-text', ['inside', 'outside', 'none']],
  ['hand', ['normal', 'hollow']]
])

function utilityClock(container) {
  
  var dynamic = container.querySelector('.dynamic')
  var hourElement = container.querySelector('.hour')
  var minuteElement = container.querySelector('.minute')
  var secondElement = container.querySelector('.second')
  
  var div = function(className, innerHTML) {
    var element = document.createElement('div')
    element.className = className
    element.innerHTML = innerHTML || ''
    return element
  }

  var append = function(element) {
    return {
      to: function(parent) {
        parent.appendChild(element)
        return append(parent)
      }
    }
  }

  var anchor = function(element, rotation) {
    var anchor = div('anchor')
    rotate(anchor, rotation)
    append(element).to(anchor).to(dynamic)
  }
  
  var minute = function(n) {
    var klass = n % 5 == 0 ? 'major' : n % 1 == 0 ? 'whole' : 'part'
    var line = div('element minute-line ' + klass)
    anchor(line, n)
    if (n % 5 == 0) {
      var text = div('anchor minute-text ' + klass)
      var content = div('expand content', (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n)
      append(content).to(text)
      rotate(text, -n)
      anchor(text, n)
    }
  }

  var hour = function(n) {
    var klass = 'hour-item hour-' + n
    var line = div('element hour-pill ' + klass)
    anchor(line, n * 5)
    var text = div('anchor hour-text ' + klass)
    var content = div('expand content', n)
    append(content).to(text)
    rotate(text, -n * 5)
    anchor(text, n * 5)
    return
  }

  var position = function(element, phase, r) {
    var theta = phase * 2 * Math.PI
    element.style.top = (-r * Math.cos(theta)).toFixed(1) + 'px'
    element.style.left = (r * Math.sin(theta)).toFixed(1) + 'px'
  }

  var rotate = function(element, second) {
    element.style.transform = element.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + (second * 6) + 'deg)'
  }

  var animate = function() {
    var now = new Date()
    var time = now.getHours() * 3600 +
                now.getMinutes() * 60 +
                now.getSeconds() * 1 +
                now.getMilliseconds() / 1000
    rotate(secondElement, time)
    rotate(minuteElement, time / 60)
    rotate(hourElement, time / 60 / 12)
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }

  for (var i = 1 / 4; i <= 60; i += 1 / 4) minute(i)
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i ++) hour(i)

  animate()

}

function autoResize(element, nativeSize) {
  var update = function() {
    var parent = element.offsetParent
    var scale = Math.min(parent.offsetWidth, parent.offsetHeight) / nativeSize
    element.style.transform = element.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + scale.toFixed(3) + ')'
  }
  update()
  window.addEventListener('resize', update)
}

function choose(clock, items) {
  var chooser = document.querySelector('#chooser')
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    var name = item[0]
    var styles = item[1]
    var element = document.createElement('div')
    element.addEventListener('click', click, false)
    update()
    chooser.appendChild(element)
    function update() {
      element.innerHTML = name + '-style-<b>' + getValue() + '</b>'
    }
    function klass(c) {
      return name + '-style-' + c
    }
    function getValue() {
      for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i ++) {
        if (clock.classList.contains(klass(styles[i]))) return styles[i]
      }
    }
    function click(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i ++) {
        if (clock.classList.contains(klass(styles[i]))) {
          clock.classList.remove(klass(styles[i]))
          clock.classList.add(klass(styles[(i + 1) % styles.length]))
          break
        }
      }
      update()
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.clock {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.centre {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.expand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.anchor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 296px;
}

.circle-1 {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.circle-2 {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #FA9F22;
}

.second {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.minute {
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}

.second-hand {
  width: 2px;
  background: #FA9F22;
}
.second-hand-front {
  width: 2px;
  height: 137px;
  background: #FA9F22;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-3px);
}
.second-hand-back {
  width: 2px;
  height: 21px;
  background: #FA9F22;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(24px);
}

.hour {
  transform: rotate(304.5deg);
}

.thin-hand {
  width: 4px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-5px);
}

.fat-hand {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 10px;
  height: 57px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-18px);
}

.minute-hand {
  height: 112px;
}


.minute-line {
  background: white;
  width: 1px;
  height: 9px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-131px);
  opacity: 0.34;
}
.major.minute-line {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.minute-text {
  font: 12px Avenir Next, Helvetica;
  color: white;
  top: -135px;
}

.hour-pill {
  background: white;
  width: 6px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-85px);
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.hour-text {
  font: 40px Hei, Helvetica;
  color: white;
  top: -105px;
}
.hour-10 .content {
  padding-left: 0.4ex;
}
.hour-11 .content {
  padding-left: 0.25ex;
}

/* Now, customizations! */


/* Customize: hour */
.hour-style-text .hour-pill {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hour-style-pill .hour-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-1.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-2.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-3.hour-pill,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-4.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-5.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-6.hour-pill,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-7.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-8.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-9.hour-pill,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-10.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-11.hour-text,
.hour-style-text-quarters .hour-12.hour-pill {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Customize: hour-text */
.hour-text-style-small .hour-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  top: -113px;
}

/* Customize: hour-display */
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-1,
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-2,
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-4,
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-5,
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-7,
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-8,
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-10,
.hour-display-style-quarters .hour-11 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hour-display-style-none .hour-item {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Customize: minute */
.minute-style-dot .minute-line {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-134px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.minute-style-dot .part.minute-line,
.minute-style-dot.hour-style-pill .major.minute-line {
  opacity: 0;
}
.minute-style-dot .hour-pill {
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-100px);
  height: 40px;
}

/* Customize: minute text */
.minute-text-style-inside .major.minute-line {
  opacity: 0;
}
.minute-text-style-outside .minute-text {
  top: -152px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.minute-text-style-none .minute-text {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Customize: Minute display */
.minute-style-line.minute-display-style-fine-2 .whole.minute-line,
.minute-style-line.minute-display-style-fine-2 .major.minute-line {
  height: 13px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-127px);
}
.minute-style-line.minute-display-style-fine-2 .part.minute-line {
  height: 8px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%) translateY(-132px);
}
.minute-display-style-coarse .part.minute-line {
  opacity: 0;
}
.minute-display-style-major .part.minute-line,
.minute-display-style-major .whole.minute-line {
  opacity: 0;
}
.minute-display-style-none .part.minute-line,
.minute-display-style-none .major.major.minute-line,
.minute-display-style-none .whole.minute-line {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Customize: hand */
.hand-style-hollow .fat-hand {
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

/* Customizer */
#chooser {
  font: 2vw Arial, sans-serif;  //10px  Verdana;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;  // 4px;
  left: 4px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;  // 0.5;
  
}
#chooser div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#chooser div:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}       

.fill {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 5em auto 0;
}


@media (max-width:500px)  {
body {
  background: red;
}

#chooser {
  font: 4vw Arial, sans-serif;  //10px  Verdana;
   top: 3em;  // 4px;
}

}
```

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - [v2] Apple Watch Face Imitation (Customizable)</title>



</head>
<body>

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="todo">
<div id="chooser">

</div>
<p style="position: relative; top:-.5em; left: -4px; color: wheat; font-weight:bold;">· Puedes cambiar el aspecto.</p>
<div class="fill">

  <div class="clock
              hour-style-pill
              hour-text-style-large
              hour-display-style-all
              minute-style-line
              minute-display-style-fine-2
              minute-text-style-outside
              hand-style-hollow
              " id="utility-clock">
    <div class="centre">
        <div class="dynamic"></div>
        <div class="expand round circle-1"></div>
        <div class="anchor hour">
            <div class="element thin-hand"></div>
            <div class="element fat-hand"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="anchor minute">
            <div class="element thin-hand"></div>
            <div class="element fat-hand minute-hand"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="anchor second">
            <div class="element second-hand second-hand-front"></div>
            <div class="element second-hand second-hand-back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="expand round circle-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->


</body>
</html>
```

He encontrado este reloj que me viene bien para enseñar a los críos las horas. El problema que tengo es que no consigo hacerle funcionar a las media queries para pantalla menor de 500. He probado con la nueva sintaxis de queries pero tampoco va. ¿Alquien me puede dar alguna pista? He probado en distintos navegadores a reducir el tamaño y sí que va. Veo que aquí se ejecuta bien. Yo creo que el problema puede estar en Android pues no me da el fondo rojo en width menor de 500.

Gracias de antemano.

--- No sé cómo insertar la página. He probado muchas veces a colocar en su sitio html, javascript y css pero no hay manera de publicarla. ¿Algún modo?

Comment: Dale al botón `<>` en el editor donde estas escribiendo la pregunta y te aparecerá el creador de snippets de código donde tienes campos para todo eso y ademas puedes ejecutar código

Comment: Gracias. Sí, si lo he hecho ya casi 10 veces, pero me dice que mi pregunta es de código y que he de poner más detalles. No me deja enviar. Y entra en bucle. Siempre trato de facilitar las cosas, pero aquí estoy llegando a la irritación.

Comment: Parece que ya lo lograstes :-)

Comment: Ahora sí, al enviar primero la pregunta y luego, después, editarla, me ha dejado.

Comment: Prueba cambiar la media query a esto:  `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) { body {   background: red; } }`.. si funciona lo pongo en la respuesta

Comment: Revise de muchos modos por que dices que no funciona, hasta que finalmente lei que es en Android en donde no funciona. Por favor, detalla de mejor manera que el problema es en android.

Comment: Muchas gracias, masterguru. Sí, ahora sí ha funcionado. Ayer, probé muchas veces con screen, pero me faltó only pues en otras páginas que tengo me funcionaba sin el  only ni el device. Ya puedo arreglar los tamaños pues estaba probando primero con el fondo.

Comment: Acabo de publicar la respuesta para que conste.  Acéptala para darle más visibilidad y que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente. Y si acaso cambia el título agregando "en Android" al final para que se encuentre mejor.

Comment: @masterguru agregue es detalle al titulo.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, tambien he visto que esa sintaxis aparece en [W3Schools de ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) de las media queries.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, masterguru: ¿Está ya aceptada? Es que no lo veo bien.

Comment: @Caminante, si, ahora si, gracias por colaborar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según parece es un problema conocido en Android y una solución es poner la `media queries` en el CSS de esta forma:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) { 
  body {   background: red; } 
}
```

El crédito es para [esta página](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082770/css-media-queries-not-working-for-android-device) donde exponen idéntico problema (¡desde el año 2014!).

También aparece de este modo en el ejemplo de [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) donde hay información ampliada de la sintaxis usada.