# Los estilos de CSS no se aplican con un media query

Tags: javascript, css, html5, dom, eventos

Tengo un CSS que no me toma los media querys. Le quiero aplicar una `font-size: 5px` y no se aplica. Les comparto mi CSS, mi HTML y mi JS.

```js
svgCart.onclick = () => {
  let section = document.getElementById('carrito');

  if (section.classList.contains('noShow')) {
    svgCart.classList.add('noShow');
    section.classList.remove('noShow');
    section.classList.add('show');

  } else {
    section.classList.remove('show');
    section.classList.add('noShow');
    svgCart.classList.remove('noShow')
  }
}
```

```css
#carrito.show {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 40vh;
  top: 30%;
  right: 2%;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 40vh;
  padding-top: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#carrito.show .selectOption {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#carrito.show .selectOption div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#carrito.show .selectOption svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#carrito.show .selectOption p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

   @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #carrito.show .selectOption {
font-size: 5px;
  }
}


#carrito.noShow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42" fill="currentColor" id="svgCart" class="bi bi-cart svgCart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
</svg>

<section id="carrito" class="noShow">
  <div class="selectOption" id="selectOption">
    <div>
      <p>Eliminar Producto</p>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-circle" id="svgEliminar" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z" />
        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <p id="textoPrecio">Precio: $</p>

  </div>

</section>
```

Quisiera saber que está fallando. Intenté comprobando el CSS, pero no tuve ninguna solución. Muchas Gracias por tu tiempo. :)

Comment: ¿A qué o cuáles elementos le querés aplicar ese tamaño de fuente?

Comment: Al p de eliminar producto y a precio

Comment: Achiqué el ancho hasta llegar a menos de 480 px y el tamaño de fuente es muy pequeño (asumo que sí se aplicaron los estilos). No puedo reproducir el error.

Comment: Si el problema está en los dispositivos móbiles android prueba con `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {` (lo puse en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506798/no-me-funcionan-las-media-queries-en-este-reloj-android/506806#506806) hace un tiempo)

Comment: no te falta `svgCart = document.getElementById('svgEliminar');` al principio del javascript?

Comment: Sep! Ya lo solucioné. Muchas Gracias @masterguru

Comment: Muchas gracias @padaleiana!

Comment: Bueno, cuidado, que el jsfiddle no habias puesto el svg con id='svgCart' que si vemos en la pregunta

Comment: A escribirlo como respuesta y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) entonces :)

Comment: Eso, pon la respuesta porque me he perdido, no se si ahora consigues aplicar el CSS o consigues pulsar el icono, o ambas cosas, ni cual ha sido la solución final que te va bien.

Comment: ¡Recordá que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas! La respuesta debe ir, _detallada_, **en la zona de respuestas**, no como edición a tu pregunta.

Comment: Si la respuesta es solo esa entonces esta duplicada aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506798/no-me-funcionan-las-media-queries-en-este-reloj-android/506806#506806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica si esto te funciona

```
@media screen and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #carrito.show .selectOption {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
```

Pero segun tu css creo que te quedaria mejor asi

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #carrito.show .selectOption {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
```

Para que asi se active los de 480px para abajo.

Comment: Hola Jeff! No me funcionó!! No puedo dar con la tecla :(