# ¿Qué tamaño poner en "media" para que funcione en todas las pantallas móviles?

Tags: css, css3

Llevo un tiempo buscando información sobre MEDIA, y qué tamaño poner en px para cubrir la gran mayoría de pantallas móviles. He buscado información por internet pero no me sale nada especifico de qué mínimo y máximo poner.
Dado el problema que, en mi portafolio, no sé hacer que mi página funcione en móviles perfectamente sin importar la pantalla, si alguien fuera tan amable de decirme dónde buscar una guía de medidas o qué hay que hacer en estos casos, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Mírate esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/506806/263200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi estimado estos son los estandares actuales, incluye tambien para los televisores, ya que los mismos permiten navegacion...

```
480px: Moviles
768px: Tablets
1024px: Laptops
1200px: Computadoras de Escritorio
1300px en adelante: Extra largo y aqui se incluye la familia de TV.
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: en caso de los móviles se usaría  @media screen and (max-width: 480;) no?,  es la duda que tengo ya que no encuentre lo que me acabas de mandar

Comment: Si, es correcto, y así el código se aplica desde allí hacia abajo en términos de dimensiones.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar las dimensiones de small, para que funcione en un buen numero de dispositivos.

[image: information columns]